# Is there any good reason to use window.setTimeout instead of setTimeout?

Tags: javascript

I see only one case where I should use `window.setTimeout` instead of `setTimeout`, it is when I have reused the name `setTimeout` in my closure, which is obviously not so good a practice (unless very specific use).

I noticed that Google Closure compiler does not remove `window.`. Since it is so aggressive in reducing variable names, I wondered if they have any reason for that?

Is there any other reason I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `window.setTimeout`, you're sure to use `window.setTimeout`. That might not be a case if the `setTimeout` variable was shadowed in your scope.

If you're sure you didn't shadow this variable, you might not bother, but the Closure compiler has no way to be sure, one of the reasons being that the context of a function can be provided dynamically.